# How to call an existing onclick function outside component?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, react-router, frontend

I have an onclick function for my menu bars in my `Navbar.js` component and I want to call it in my `App.js` so that I could move some specific pages in my website to the right when I toggle the menu bars.

Here's my `App.js`, the route inside div with the className of mainpage is the route/page I want to move whenever I toggle the menubars

```
function App() {
  
  return (
    
    <AuthProvider>
      <Router>
      <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Navubaru}/>
      <div className="mainpage">
      <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
      </div>
      </Router>
    <Container className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style={{ minHeight: "100vh"}}>
      <div className="w-100" style={{maxWidth:'400px'}}>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard}/>
            <Route path="/signup" component={Signup}/>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <Route path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword}/>
            <Route path="/update-profile" component={UpdateProfile}/>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    
    </Container>
    </AuthProvider>
  )}

export default App
```

here's my `Navbar.js` it contains both the sidebar and navbar, It also contains the onClick function im trying to call in App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {Navbar, Container} from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext"
import './styles/styles.css';
import * as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa';
import * as AiIcons from 'react-icons/ai';
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons';
import { SidebarItem } from './SidebarItem';

export default function Navubaru({component: Component, ...rest}) {
    const { currentUser } = useAuth()
    const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);

    const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);
    return (
        <div>
            
    <Navbar bg="myColor" variant="dark">
    <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: '#fff' }}>
        <Link to='#' className='menu-bars'>
              <FaIcons.FaBars onClick={showSidebar} />
        </Link>
        <nav className={sidebar ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
            <ul className='nav-menu-items' onClick={showSidebar}>
              <li className='navbar-toggle'>
                <Link to='#' className='menu-bars'>
                  <AiIcons.AiOutlineClose />
                </Link>
              </li>
              {SidebarItem.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                    <Link to={item.path}>
                      {item.icon}
                      <span>{item.title}</span>
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                );
              })}
            </ul>
          </nav>
        
    
    
    </IconContext.Provider>
    <Container>
    <div className={sidebar ? 'navactive':'navclose'}>
    <Navbar.Brand href="/">Customer Intelligence System</Navbar.Brand>
    </div>
    <Navbar.Toggle />
    <Navbar.Collapse className="justify-content-end">
      <Navbar.Text>
        Signed in as: <a href="/">{currentUser && currentUser.email}</a>
      </Navbar.Text>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Container>
    </Navbar>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's easy to call any assigned event of one component from another component or file.
Here you will need knowledge of these hooks.

```
useRef()
forwardRef()
```

Here I've passed this component through forwardRef hook so that I can call any assigned event of this component from another component or file. Like app.js

```
/**
*
* Navbar.js 
*
*/
import { forwardRef  } from "react";

const Navbar = (props, ref) => {

  const onClickHandler = () => {
     alert('clicked the inner button');
  }

 return (
    <button onClick={onClickHandler} ref={ref} {...props}>  Inner Component Button </button>
   )
}

export default forwardRef( Navbar )
```

This is my app.js file where I called the the event by using useRef hook

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
const App = () => {
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);
  
  const outerClickHandler = () => {
    if( buttonRef.current ) {
      buttonRef.current.click()
    }
  }
  
  return (
  <div className="App">
    <button onClick={outerClickHandler}> Outer button </button>
       <Navbar ref={buttonRef}/>
  </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

just export the function and then import by name in App.js

eg:

```
//NavBar.js
export const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);

//App.js
import { showSidebar } from ./path/to/NavBar.js
```

then do whatever you want

Also as a note, the proper way to update state which references previous state is by using a callback.

```
export const showSidebar = () => setSidebar((oldState) => !oldState)
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates